# Capacitive touch screen(HannStar HSD070PWW5) interface with Pi

Tags: touchscreen

I have a 7" hannstar HSD070PWW5 touchscreen. How can I connect it to a Pi? Is there a driver board that can convert the connectors to HDMI/USB for video and touch? Or is there another way to interface it with a Pi? My first preference is to get the video working.
The touch controller part number is FT5526EEZ.

Images: https://imgur.com/a/qpBTUWX